# Css Code Unexpectly Stopped functioning after change of script

Tags: html, css

I have attached a copy of my code. My Articles of text aren't formatting or working properly if someone could please help me understand show me how to fix this. They use to look like grey/dark grey boxes centred in the middle of the screen formatted nicely. Now it wont even change the background colour of anything on the page. Thanks!
- Cale

```css
header
{
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: DarkCyan;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    top: -10;
    height: 150px;
    left: -10;
    width: 105%;
    z-index:5;
}
header a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: white;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: -1;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}
p.articleheader
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: -1;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
article.art1class
{
    text-align:center;
    color: silver;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    background-color: midnightblue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 162;
    lefT: -0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5;

}
ul.menu li {
    float: left;
}
ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    transition: background-color 0.01s;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <TITLE>Multicultural Festival - Home</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <HEADER>
        <a name="top" href="#home"><H1>Multicultural Festival</H1></a>
    </HEADER>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li style="width:25%"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li style="width:25%"><a href="Events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li style="width:25%"><a href="Location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li style="width:25%"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br>
    <ARTICLE class="art1class">
        <p class="articleheader">#1 Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge</p>
        <hr>
        <p>
            Last year's Galaxy S6 Edge was a good phone,
            but not brilliant. It was the same as the Samsung Galaxy S6,
            but had a curved screen - and that was it. It was the same size, power and camera,
            and that wasn't enough.
            Fast forward to today and the S7 Edge takes all the great looks of the S6 Edge,
            makes the phone even curvier and combines it with the superb power and feature set of the S7.
            The camera is just brilliant, the mix of metal and glass is really nice to hold, and even the
            Touchwiz overlay is turning into something more usable than before.
            Battery life improvements are hugely welcomed, and while the price is higher,
            it's now affixed to a phone that offers simply the best in nearly every department,
            so many will be happy with the outlay.
        </p>
        <hr>
    </ARTICLE>
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><hr><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br>
</BODY>
<FOOTER>
    <NAV>
        All Copyright reserved to Cale &copy; Creation Date: 08/06/2018<br>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a> | <a href="#home">Home</a> | <a href="brands.html">Brands</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </NAV>
</FOOTER>
</HTML>
```

Comment: check you css path. I think you change folder structure and move css from root directory to sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the above code in my text editor and it worked fine. CSS is working exactly as you defined in the description. 
I think the problem is with the linking of your CSS file.
Check the address again and check for Uppercase/Lowercase Mistakes

[Image showing the Proper Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAdQF.png)

I even changed the background color and it worked.

Code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <TITLE>Multicultural Festival - Home</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <HEADER>
            <a name="top" href="#home"><H1>Multicultural Festival</H1></A>
        </HEADER>

        <ul class= "menu">
          <li style="width:25%"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li style="width:25%"><a href="Events.html">Events</a></li>
          <li style="width:25%"><a href="Location.html">Location</a></li>
          <li style="width:25%"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br>
        <ARTICLE class="art1class">
        <p class="articleheader">#1 Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge</p>
        <hr>
                <p>Last year's Galaxy S6 Edge was a good phone, 
                but not brilliant. It was the same as the Samsung Galaxy S6, 
                but had a curved screen - and that was it. It was the same size, power and camera,
                and that wasn't enough.
                Fast forward to today and the S7 Edge takes all the great looks of the S6 Edge,
                makes the phone even curvier and combines it with the superb power and feature set of the S7.
                The camera is just brilliant, the mix of metal and glass is really nice to hold, and even the
                Touchwiz overlay is turning into something more usable than before. 
                Battery life improvements are hugely welcomed, and while the price is higher, 
                it's now affixed to a phone that offers simply the best in nearly every department, 
                so many will be happy with the outlay.
</p>
        <hr>
        </ARTICLE>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><hr><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br>
            </BODY>
        <FOOTER>
            <NAV>
                All Copyright reserved to Cale &copy; Creation Date: 08/06/2018<br>
                <a href="home.html">Home</a> | <a href="#home">Home</a> | <a href="brands.html">Brands</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </NAV>
        </FOOTER>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
    color: white;       
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: DarkCyan;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    top: -10;
    height: 150px;
    left: -10;
    width: 105%;
    z-index:5;
}       
header a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: white;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: -1;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}
p.articleheader
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: -1;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
article.art1class
{
    text-align:center;
    color: silver;          
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    background-color: midnightblue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 162;
    lefT: -0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5;

}
ul.menu li {
    float: left;
}
ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.01s;
    transition: background-color 0.01s;
}
```